# Drupal8 How to create a link to an entity add form in twig

Tags: drupal-8

Can I use the path() function in twig to create a link to an entity add form. Taking the group module as an example, if I want to create a link to the 'group/add' page in twig can I use something like:

```
{{ path(entity.group.add) }}
```

I know that the above does not work, neither does

```
{{ path(group.add) }}
```

Not sure if there is a way to do this with the various twig functions that create links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the first action in the `group.links.action.yml` file, you should use this:

```
{{ path('entity.group.add_page') }}
```